# C++ Set Window Text issue

Tags: c++, winapi

Ok, I have a file.txt which has this contents:

```
xzline1\n
xzline2\n
```

When I run it, the window contains this:

```
xzline1\nxzline2\n
```

and not

```
xzline1
xzline2
```

Not recognizing the \n new line characters, not sure why.

My window is defined like this

```
        LPCWSTR recordin;
        HWND hEdit;
        hEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), NULL,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_MAXIMIZE | ES_MULTILINE,
            10, 10, 200, 25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)NULL, NULL, NULL);
       std::ifstream t("c://file.txt");
       std::stringstream buffer;
       buffer << t.rdbuf();
       std::wstring stemp = s2ws(buffer.str());
       recordin = stemp.c_str();
       SetWindowText(hEdit, recordin);

           std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
           {
              int len;
              int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
              len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
              wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
              MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
              std::wstring r(buf);
              delete[] buf;
              return r;
            }
```

Comment: Does your file literally contain a backslash ('\') followed by an 'n' at the end of each line, or did my formatting attempt instead occlude the issue?

Comment: Yes, each line contains \n at the end. I actually tried it without the \n and it just displayed everything on one line like this xzline1xzline2

Comment: I wrote an answer below. But if you literally have a "slash" and an "n" in your text file, the answer still mostly applies.  You got to convert your end of line indicators to `"\r\n"` for windows to interpret it as end-of-line marker for the edit control.

Comment: Is this `\n` single char with code 10 (0x0A) or it is "back-slash-lowercase-N"? Probably the second (wrong) because you have "\n" in "xzline1\nxzline2\n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic Windows common controls wants DOS line endings, `\r\n`.  Convert all those `\n` chars to be `\r\n`.

Probably can just do this as a quick hack:

```
 std::wstring stemp = s2ws(buffer.str());

 // quick and dirty string copy with DOS to to unix conversions
 std::wstring stemp2;
 for (char ch : stemp) {
    if (ch == '\n') {
        stemp2 += "\r";
    }
    stemp2 += ch;
 }

 recordin = stemp2.c_str();
 SetWindowText(hEdit, recordin);
```

Alternatively, it's very likely your `input.txt` is written out as a standard Windows text file with `\r\n` line endings and the C++ runtime is just converting all those `\r\n` instances to `\n` chars.  If that's the case, you can just open the file as binary so the conversion doesn't happen.

Replace this:

```
std::ifstream t("c://file.txt");
```

With this:

```
std::ifstream t("c://file.txt", std::ios::binary);
```